# ほど translation in this sentence

Tags: translation, reading-comprehension, jlpt

[image]

How to translate this ストレスの多い人**ほど**よく夢を見る ?
Could someone give me full translation of this whole question ?

I currently understand that ほど in this context is used to show an extent but I can't translate and understand it anyway.

I've seen this kind of usage. For example, やらなければならない仕事が山ほどある(I have works too much and it feels like a mountain), I think I can understand this because there's が indicating what feels like a mountain(works).

But in the sentence I gave, there's no subject mentioned (I think it's omitted but I don't know what's it) "ストレスの多い人はストレスの多い人ほど良く夢を見る" is what I think to be the full sentence but it sounds really weird. Another assumption is "ストレスの多い人になるほど良く夢を見る"

I don't know if the following picture is relevant or not. But it's reading comprehension that this question according to.

[image]

The context starts where the red arrow pointing. I just give full article to give all information I have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This ほど is "the more ～ (the more ～)". It's a variation of the ～ば～ほど construction.

> ストレスの多い人**ほど**よく夢を見る。
> = ストレスの多い人**であればあるほど**よく夢を見る。

> The more one has stress, the more often they dream (*or* "the longer they dream").

ほど following a noun (or a noun phrase) that is associated with some comparable "trait" (強い人, 天才, バカ, 泣き虫, 金持ち, 美人, ...) can work like this.

Examples:

- 金持ちほどお金の大切さを知っている。
  The richer you are, the more you know the importance of money.
- 弱い犬ほどよく吠える。
  Barking dogs seldom bite. (lit. The weaker a dog is, the more it barks.)
- 賢い人ほど謙虚だ。
  The wiser a person is, the more humble he is.
- 北に住むクマほど体が大きい。
  The further north a bear lives, the bigger its body is.

Comment: This is a better answer than mine so I have removed mine to avoid confusion.