# ～ば～ほど with noun + omission

Tags: grammar, omission

I said that I wasn't confident with my Japanese to a Japanese person, and that person said to me:

> 上手な人ほど自信がないよね

I didn't understand the meaning because ほど can slightly change the meaning depending on the usage, so I used Google Translate and it returned:

> The more skilled people are, the less confident they are.

Then, the first thing I did was to confirm that ～ば～ほど could be used with nouns. It seems it can be used with nouns but I didn't find many example sentences, it seems to be uncommon, but I also found that you can actually omit some parts of that ～ば～ほど structure[¹](https://bunpro.jp/grammar_points/%E3%81%B0-%E3%81%BB%E3%81%A9)[²](https://www.edewakaru.com/archives/10008729.html), like, instead of saying:

> 勉強すれば勉強するほど上手になる

you can omit 勉強すれば and say

> 勉強するほど上手になる

So, does the sentence the Japanese person said to me means the same as below? Also, can I rewrite it as the second way below? Finally, I'm not sure but it seems that I can also use なら or ならば instead of であれば. Can I also rewrite it as the third and fourth way? For example, it seems that when あるほど is not being used, you directly connect ほど to the noun instead of using の like "人のほど".

> 上手な人であれば上手な人であるほど自信がないよね
>
> 上手な人であればあるほど自信がないよね
>
> 上手な人ならば上手な人ほど自信がないよね
>
> 上手な人なら上手な人ほど自信がないよね

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main part of your question is covered by my previous answer, so please read this first:
[ほど translation in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/77948/5010)

> it seems that I can also use なら or ならば instead of であれば.

I don't think so...

- 上手な人であれば上手な人であるほど自信がないよね: Grammatically perfect, but sounds fairly wordy
- 上手な人であればあるほど自信がないよね: Perfect
- 上手な人ならば上手な人ほど自信がないよね: Understandable but highly questionable
- 上手な人なら上手な人ほど自信がないよね: Acceptable but unnatural

人のほど seems simply ungrammatical.

Comment: As I thought, there's a difference between *being able to use with nouns* and *being able to use with nouns associated with a strong "trait"*. When I saw that 上手な I felt it made sense to use it. Also, many websites teach some weird constructions, like the ones I mentioned, but I also never saw them being used. Thanks!