Usage of ほど in this contenxt
人って複雑じゃん。　本当は怒ってるのに笑ってたり。　本当は喜んでるのに無表情だったり。
何事にも外面と内面があってちぐはぐだったりギャップがあるほど面白い
Since in everything, there is an outward face and hidden face, they are mismatched.
The character explains why he became an actor.  I understand what the sentence is saying up to the last part.
何事にも外面と内面があってちぐはぐだったりギャップがあるほど面白い
I'm not sure how to take the ほど here? I understand "to the degree of x" but I don't see how it fits? The other grammar I can think of is "the more there's" but it's no complete as far I can see.

Does this answer your question:  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/77948/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/243/9831

ギャップがあるほど is a "short" version of ギャップがあればあるほど. Please see the chocolate's links. Also, you've missed the たり-たり construction where the second たり is omitted:

何事にも外面と内面があってちぐはぐだったりギャップがあるほど面白い。
→ 何事にも外面と内面があって、ちぐはぐだったりギャップがあったりすればするほど面白い。
Everything has an exterior and interior; the more mismatched or discordant they are, the more interesting they are.

